# node querystring not defined in script only

Tags: node.js, query-string

I can use querystring in node 4.2.6 from a script, but I can from a node prompt.  Here's some proof.

I have the following script:

```
$ cat test.js
console.log(process.versions)
console.log(querystring)
```

And I get an error when I run it:

```
$ node test.js
{ http_parser: '2.5.0',
  node: '4.2.6',
  v8: '4.5.103.35',
  uv: '1.8.0',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '46',
  openssl: '1.0.2e' }
/path/to/file/test.js:2
console.log(querystring)
            ^
ReferenceError: querystring is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/file/test.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

But if I go into node on the command line, I don't get the error.

```
$ node
> console.log(process.versions)
{ http_parser: '2.5.0',
  node: '4.2.6',
  v8: '4.5.103.35',
  uv: '1.8.0',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '46',
  openssl: '1.0.2e' }
undefined
> console.log(querystring)
{ unescapeBuffer: [Function],
  unescape: [Function],
  escape: [Function],
  encode: [Function],
  stringify: [Function],
  decode: [Function],
  parse: [Function] }
undefined
```

The console.log() is just for proof--I can't use querystring at all in a script. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The node REPL (what you get when just typing the executable name (`node`)) automatically loads built-in modules as globals as they are accessed by name as a convenience. This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features).

For scripts that you load with `node foo.js` you will need to `require()` modules manually to pull in what you actually need. For the `querystring` module, you would just need to do:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
```

There is no need to `npm install querystring` as the module is built-in to node.

Comment: thanks for the reference to the docs that explains the pain point

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ npm install querystring
```